# split view url parameter passing and dynamically loading the pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, github, ipad

I am a newbie on a jquery mobile platform.. I am facing the following problem

http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

I am refering this site example for my app.

No the problem is.. here everything coded is static... that is the information coming in the left panel as well as right is static.

I want the same thing to be dynamic and hence the data in my case is coming from the local database.

Now, the left panel gets loaded perfectly in my case.
For the time.. when I click on the item (in the left panel), the right panel loads perfectly...

Immediately later when I click on any other item, the right panel does not load...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: too confusing. Please give clear specification where you felt problem or where you stuck. Also put some code for reference

Comment: my only problem is that the right panel in the example should popup dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Try using simplesplitview

http://simplesplitview.sourceforge.net/

Its quite simple and easy to implement.